# Exception Details Not Showing on Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a C# functions app and have this code block in a function:

```
try
{
    var purchaseItem = await PurchaseCatalogItemForAzureServer.PurchaseItem(serverApi, "----", null);
    if (purchaseItem.isError)
        return purchaseItem.ToNonGeneric();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Id: " + id + " E: " + e.ToString());
}
```

When my custom exception trigger I see this stacktrace on application insights:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at AzureFunctionsForPM2.PurchaseItem+<Run>d__0.MoveNext (AzureFunctionsForPM2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\TestFuctionApp\AzureFunctionsForPM2\AzureFunctionsForPM2\Item\Functions\PurchaseItem.cs:125)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
```

As you can see my custom exception not showing, just pointing to line number of my custom exception line and shows "Inner exception System.Exception handled at bla bla bla" that's all.

I don't have any class to inherit FunctionsStartup or Startup class in functions project.

My host.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging":
    {
        "LogLevel":
        {
          "Default": "Error",
          "System": "Error",
          "Microsoft": "Error",
          "Host.Results": "Error",
          "Function": "Error",
          "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
        },
        "applicationInsights":
        {
            "samplingSettings":
            {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request;Dependency;Event;PageView;Trace"
            },
            
            "enableDependencyTracking": false,
            "EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
            
            "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": false,
            "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false,
            
            "enableLiveMetrics": true,
            "EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
            "EnableEventCounterCollectionModule": false,
            "EnableAppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect anyway? You're not throwing a custom exception type. You basically throw a new exception that is not related to the catched exception (you did not include the original exception as the inner exception. You could just as well not catch it at all.

Comment: Check out the `exceptions` collection, not just `traces`.

Comment: @PeterBons I already include the original exception in catch block by use e.ToString()

Comment: That is not how to do that, to throw an exception and include the original exception  use the proper overload like `throw new Exception("Id: " + id + " E: " + e.ToString(), e);`. But then again, I am not sure what kind of output you expect. Unless your code is some demo code it has no use whatsoever to just throw a new exception with no additional information than the caught exception already provides.

Comment: I just need to detail of exception; even if I do not add a try catch, when that exception occurs, it still gives me a non-detailed exception information on Application Insights. I just need to get detail of exception, where does the exception occur? In which class?Which function? Which line number? If I debug function locally, the details of the exception are given seamlessly as I want. The problem is on the Application Insights side. I don't want anything too difficult, just want to see exception details in Application Insights as in local debugs @PeterBons

Comment: But it is literally here: `Inner exception System.Exception handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at AzureFunctionsForPM2.PurchaseItem+<Run>d__0.MoveNext (AzureFunctionsForPM2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\TestFuctionApp\AzureFunctionsForPM2\AzureFunctionsForPM2\Item\Functions\PurchaseItem.cs:125)` -> Exception of type System.Exception in PurchaseItem.cs:125. That's why I am confused about the question

Comment: PurchaseItem.cs:125 is pointing to this line : 
```
throw new Exception("Id: " + id + " E: " + e.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same stack trace when you run like below:

[image]

To get detailed information on this first connect your function to Application Insights:

[image]

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=84e62;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

After running the function app, you can check exceptions in Logs of the application insights you have connection your function app to.

[image]

[image]

You can also check exceptions in transaction section as below:

[image]

[image]

This is how exceptions are shown in Azure Portal.